# Sonata user bundle and FosUserBundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, sonata-admin, sonata-user-bundle

At the beginning I installed FosUserBundle and extended the base user class:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
*/
class User extends BaseUser
{

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 *
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please enter your name.", groups={"Registration", "Profile"})
 * @Assert\Length(
 *     min=3,
 *     max=255,
 *     minMessage="The name is too short.",
 *     maxMessage="The name is too long.",
 *     groups={"Registration", "Profile"}
 * )
 */
protected $name;


/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="House", mappedBy="User")
 */
private $houses;
. . .
```

after that I installed sonata admin bundle,sonata easy extend and sonata user bundle. The problem now is that when I try to go to /register page
I have this error:

```
Neither the property "name" nor one of the methods "name()", "getname()"/"isname()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" in FOSUserBundle:Registration:register_content.html.twig at line 36
```

I am bit confused, which entity user should I implement (FosUSer or Sonata)?

Comment: Sonata user bundle extends fosuser bundle it good to use easy extend bundle of sonata user bundle which by default resides in `src/Application` and in this child bundle do your customization add fields etc

Comment: if Sonata extends fosuser why I have this error?

Comment: Because in sonata's extended entity there is no `name` property is defined thats why you are getting this error

Comment: I added name property and his getter and setter but still the same . . .

Comment: You have added property definition in entity or in xml file , by default sonata uses `*.orm.xml` files for entity definition & mapping you can see these files under `Resorces/config/doctrine` and don't for get to clear cache after your changes, for reference have a look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12617682/symfony2-fosuserbundle-and-sonatauserbundle-overriding-entities

Comment: Is it possible to override config directly in my app and don't modify it in Sonata bundle?